# MeshBuilder, assembly missing

Tags: xna, importing

I'm trying to build a terrain starting from a heightmap. I've already some ideas about the procedure, but I can't even get started. I feel like I have to use a [MeshBuider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.content.pipeline.graphics.meshbuilder%28v=XNAGameStudio.31%29.aspx). The problem is that Visual Studio (I'm using the 2008 version) wants an *assembly*. Effectively on the MSDN there's a line specifying the assembly needed by the MeshBuilder, but I don't know how to import/load it.
Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you trying to load this assembly at runtime?  XNA's content pipeline is designed to run at build time and is only available on windows - not XBox.  New content pipeline projects should reference this correctly with XNA installed.

Comment: @Leniency: I'm developing for windows. And no, I'm trying to load at build time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, then you need to add a reference to the content pipeline assemblies from your game project.  XNA by default won't do this.

In VS -> Project Menu -> Add Reference.  Under the .NET tab, you'll find everything.  It's helpful to sort by component name.  You're looking for the component Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.

Don't add the importers, those are for converting resources into XNA's internal format in content pipeline projects.